# Minecraft commands help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to use the setblock command to place a chest with a sunflower named 'jumping joy' in it. This is the command that I am using:

```
/setblock ~2 ~2 ~ minecraft:chest 0 destroy{Items:[id:175'Count:1,Slot:0,tag:{Name:"jumping joy"}}}]}
```

but it keeps saying `Invalid tag encountered, expected '{' as first char.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You'd need a space between "destroy"  and your nbt tag at least

Comment: As of 1.8 (i think, could be 1.7) item IDs have changed. Instead of 'id:175' you would now use 'id:double_plant'. You may need to use the 'Damage:' tag to determine the type of doubleplant it is, as i believe that double grass is the generic item in this situation

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong with this.

```
/setblock ~2 ~2 ~ minecraft:chest 0 destroy{Items:[id:175'Count:1,Slot:0,tag:{Name:"jumping joy"}}}]}
```

For one thing, there's no space after "destroy". Next, `tag:{Name:"jumping joy"}` is not the syntax to name an item. You'll need to use `tag:{display{Name:"jumping joy"}}` for that. Next, you have a single quote instead of a comma after `id:175`. Lastly, you should not be using numerical item ID's if you're in version 1.8 or later. They're depreciated in 1.8, and removed in 1.9 and upwards.